# jDateChooser casting MsSql date

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, java.util.date, jdatechooser

I have problem with capturing user date input from jDateChooser to insert into mssql table. There similar problems in stackoverflow. It was not solving my problem.

Here is code that I capture user date entry

```
obj.setStartDate(jDateChooser3.getDate());
obj.setEndDate( jDateChooser4.getDate());
```

DatabasePropeties class and SaveNewProject Method

```
        import java.math.BigDecimal;
        import java.sql.*;
        import java.util.Date;

        Date StartDate;
        Date EndDate;    

        public boolean SaveNewProject()                    
        {
            boolean resp = false;            
            paTable = connector();

            try {        
                String SPsql = "EXEC AddNewProject ? ,? ,? ,? ";
                PreparedStatement cmd = cnuser.prepareStatement(SPsql);
                cmd.setString(1, ProjectName);
                cmd.setDate(2, StartDate);
                cmd.setDate(3, EndDate);
                cmd.setString(4, ProjectCode);
                if (!cmd.execute()) {
                    resp = true;
                }
                cmd.close();
                paTable.close();        
            } catch (Exception ex) {        
                System.out.println("Error" + ex.getMessage());        
            }        
            return resp;            
        }
```

Setters and Getters

```
 public Date getStartDate() {
    return StartDate;
       }

   public void setStartDate(Date StartDate) {
    this.StartDate = StartDate;
    }

   public Date getEndDate() {
    return EndDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date EndDate) {
    this.EndDate = EndDate;
    }
```

Comment: You should be using java.sql.Date when trying to set the values in the PreparedStatement, not java.util.Date...

Comment: you mean remove import java.util.Date; ?

Comment: Not really, cause the date picker will work with java.util.Date, but when using setDate, it expects a java.sql.Date, so you'll need to convert the java.util.Date over...

Comment: let me see if understood you correctly

Comment: cmd.setDate(3, java.sql.Date(EndDate)); is correct ?

Comment: I think you'd need `new java.sql.Date(EndDate.getTime())`, but that's the idea...

Comment: I think problem is also with date format , the casting error is gone my date format is dd/MM/yyyy which I set using propeties of jDateChooser

Comment: No! Date has no concept of format, that's the point.

Comment: ok just changed the date to string  like this and push database as string SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sd = dateFormat.format(jDateChooser3.getDate());
        ed = dateFormat.format(jDateChooser4.getDate());

Comment: please post your solution and let set as answer